# How do I convert a net/http.ResponseWriter to a net/http.Response

Tags: http, go

Firstly, I intentionally asked this question incorrectly in hopes that the web search engines would better understand my intended question. The more accurate question is:

**If I have captured all calls to a custom net/http.ResponseWriter, how do take the values passed to it, that I have stored into a []byte buffer, how do I convert this to a net/http.Response?**

I believe the answer lies in net/http.ReadResponse(), but I'm not sure how to render the Response properly for ReadResponse to understand.

Comment: "captured all calls..." - What do you mean by this? Did you manage to intercept the headers/body and the status code?

Can you also post some code snippets so we can understand the problem easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [net/http/httptest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/) package has a ResponseRecorder that can convert a ResponseWriter to a Response.

If you've captured the raw http text, http.ReadResponse() can be used, but if you already parsed things like headers, status code, you could also create the `new http.Request{}` struct yourself.

Look at https://golang.org/src/net/http/response.go for details.

Comment: This does, indeed look like what I was searching for. I must say i’m a bit nervous about the name. Should I be at all concerned using this in production code?

Comment: I expect to mark this as an accepted answer, but I’m waiting on this relavant question first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808399/golang-should-i-avoid-using-net-http-httptest-in-production-code