# Should I avoid using net/http/httptest in production code?

Tags: http, go, production-environment, stability

I like the ability to present a buffered `net/http.ResponseWriter` as a `net/http.Response` in some situations which [`net/http/httptest.ResponseRecorder`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#ResponseRecorder) would give me, but the package name makes me a bit concerned about using it in production code. I understand that it’s intended to be used **primarily** for testing, but am unsure if I am asking for trouble using it in production code.

Am I tempting fate?

Comment: Why do you need present the data as an `http.Response`?  Is it sufficient to provide status, headers written by the application and body as a []byte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use this code in production. No matter what you are attempting to achieve.

`httptest.ResponseRecorder`'s ultimate purpose is to facilitate *testing*, and will thus always be extended, optimized—*rewritten*—with testing in mind. *Any* assumption can be made in this package, as long as it makes the package better at testing. The package authors intended for this to be "used in concert with `go test`"[¹](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/). I interpret that as discouraging production use, because they are then free to break e.g. your production usage in favor of `go test` usage.

Another argument is that of security. The security model of any test package is going to be that the usage is trusted, whereas non-testing code will be the opposite.

The world of software a perilous place. You are asking to make it even more perilous.

Comment: `httptest.ResponseRecorder` -- its purpose is to record responses. If you cannot rely on the "to record responses" for production use, how can you rely on it for testing then?

Comment: You can't compare production and testing like that. In testing, _I_ write the inputs, in production we must assume _anyone_ (including malignant actors) can write the inputs.

Comment: I see that you added the security point, which I partially agree with. Yet I still fail to see how "it's unreliable" point makes any sense: it must be reliable, be it for test or production. "All production usage of the package is disregarded by its authors" --- any source for that?

Comment: From [1](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/): "\[the test package\] is intended to be used in concert with the 'go test' command". I.e. it is the intention of the authors to be used in testing. I can moderate my answer, since that's strongly worded here.

Comment: But the test package is not the httptest package! And which part of the implementation could have security issues? The recorder uses a bytes.Buffer, so why is this an issue?

Comment: This is definitely an angle I hadn’t considered. I need to “sit with this answer a bit” before marking it “accepted”, but this does sound like what my gut concern was. I think you captured it quite well. Thank you.

Comment: @apxp you're right. That's a bit confusing. Feel free to remove that from the answer. I am at the moment equating the test and httptest package.